# (iPhone SDK) How to link instance variables to a specific UILabel

Tags: iphone

I'm using the iPhone SDK to build a simple application.  I've created a brand new class which has a single variable.  I need to make 5 instances of that class, which I have no trouble doing.  I can create those instances and also set the variables without issue.  What i do need to know is this:

How do I link each of the 5 different instances of the variable to different and specific UILabels?

Would I be better to create a method that dynamically creates and positions the labels?

Thanks for your help in advance, I'm now to this iphone programming thing.  I'm serious about learning fast though so I have posted a bounty on this question here :

http://www.askearn.com/Responses.aspx?QuestionID=6542613f-7be8-4bb3-a950-aac218d47711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a single view and associated view controller that contain the 5 `UILabel`s? If so, set the `text` property of each label in the `viewDidLoad` method of your `UIViewController`

With regards to the second part of your question about positioning the labels, that's up to you to decide the best way to set them. I would recommend starting out with Interface Builder first and only resorting to positioning them in code if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link UILabels with Interface Builder you need to set a few things.

```
IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

Then you should be able to link the pointer *label to a specific UILabel inside Interface Builder.

Check out [Apple's guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html) for more a more in depth tutorial.  It walks you through setting up Interface Builder.

Comment: You don't need/want 'IBOutlet' before both the ivar *and* the Property declaration. Though at first  favored putting it before the ivar it seems as though they, and most others, are now putting it in the Property declaration.